# Compiler errors

Tags: arrays, go, goroutine, channel

I've started playing with golang after reading the GOLANG-BOOK.
and I'm trying to build a simple TCP chat.
I've created a user struct, and I want to listen to every user.inbound channel from the users array.

I know my problem here is with the function writeUser() since its waiting for user.inbound. im not sure how to properly make this kind channeling with array of users.

this is the errors I recieve from the compiler:

```
./chatserver.go:22: syntax error: unexpected LCHAN, expecting )
./chatserver.go:25: non-declaration statement outside function body
./chatserver.go:31: non-declaration statement outside function body
./chatserver.go:32: syntax error: unexpected }
```

- line 22 is the func writeUser()

And this is my Code:

```
type User struct {
    name string
    inbound chan string
    outbound chan string
    conn net.Conn
}

func writeUser(user.inbound chan string) {
// how can I get the user connection?
    err := gob.NewDecoder(user.conn).Encode(inbound)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
    }
}


func (chat *Chat) broadcast(username string, message string) {
    outboundMessage := username + ": " + message;

    for _, user := range chat.users {
        user.inbound <- outboundMessage;
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited your question title - given that there is no issue here with arrays of channels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've tried to navigate to the `inbound` channel on the user in your function signature:

```
func recieve (user.inbound chan string) {
//            ^^^^^  - that part is wrong
```

You can't navigate to an objects property like that in a function argument - it doesn't really make sense. What you want in this context, is *any channel of strings*:

```
func recieve (inbound chan string) {
```

Exactly what you'll do with that channel I will leave to you (you don't seem to do anything with it in the function anyway).

The other errors are no doubt stacked from the first one - given that such an error can throw the parser out of whack.

Also, you have a few random dangling semicolons down the bottom in your `broadcast` method.

Comment: But how can I get the user inside the recieve function?
I want to recieve the user and the inbound message. so I could use the user.inbound message with the user.conn

Comment: also i've edited the question and changed the recieve function to writeUser, so you could understand I ment to do.
I ment to get the inbound message and write it back to the user using the conn from the user struct

Comment: You need to pass the user around. There is no way to navigate backward from an `inbound` channel to a `User`. Pass the `User` object along the channel and navigate _down_ to its `inbound` channel.

Comment: Is it possible to pass 2 channels together? for example: `user.inbound <- outboundMessage <- userInstance`

Comment: Not like that - but you can wrap it in another object and pass that along. E.g: `user.inbound <- Wrapper{msg: outboundMessage, u: userInstance,}`

Comment: Your question has now changed and as such we shouldn't continue this in the comments. Based on the code you've just put here, I would suggest you look over your Go book again and continue learning the language before trying to get more complicated. You're using an empty `struct{}` channel and expecting it to be of type `User` - this will not be the case. You _could_ use an `interface` and _type assertion_ .. but there is also no point in doing that - you need a concrete wrapper object as I said in my previous comment.